# How to open file in Qt application?

Tags: qt

I wrote a notepad in qt gui, but when I associate a file with it and click on it, the .exe is run and file is not opened, so I have to open it using

```
QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
                this,"Save As","",
                "Text Document (*.txt)\n All Files (*.*)")
```

When we click on text.txt it directly opens the file in notepad. How can I make same for my app?

**remark:** QDir::currentpath() returns the path of file.txtq (which is associated with it) on which we clicked but I was not able to return its name.

Comment: The file to be opened is passed as a parameter, check for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When double-clicking the file (associated with your exe), its path is passed to your program via command line arguments. You can access them in the following way:

```
if (QApplication::arguments().size() > 1) {
    const QString filename = QApplication::arguments().at(1);
    // "filename" now contains path and name of the file to open.
}
```

Also, I have no idea why you are using `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()`. In order to call the *open* file dialog, you'll need the `QDialog::getOpenFileName()` method.

Comment: Hi, the main function itself not getting hit for me. Do I have to do something for this?